# Mixitup jQuery plugin resets after selecting filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using a jQuery plugin called Mixitup to filter a portfolio page. I am having issues with it when I select a filter, it will move the objects in that category as if it is going to filter it, then resets so that all the items are showing again. Could someone help me with this issue so that the categories with filter and stay filtered? Thank you.

Js:

```
$(function () {

    var filterList = {

        init: function () {

            // MixItUp plugin
            // http://mixitup.io
            $('#portfoliolist').mixitup({
                targetSelector: '.portfolio',
                filterSelector: '.filter',
                effects: ['fade'],
                easing: 'snap',
                // call the hover effect
                onMixEnd: filterList.hoverEffect()
            });             

        },

        hoverEffect: function () {

            // Simple parallax effect
            $('#portfoliolist .portfolio').hover(
                function () {
                    $(this).find('.label').stop().animate({bottom: 0}, 200, 'easeOutQuad');
                    $(this).find('img').stop().animate({top: -30}, 500, 'easeOutQuad');             
                },
                function () {
                    $(this).find('.label').stop().animate({bottom: -40}, 200, 'easeInQuad');
                    $(this).find('img').stop().animate({top: 0}, 300, 'easeOutQuad');                               
                }       
            );              

        }

    };

    // Run the show!
    filterList.init();


});
```

Sample of HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="filters">
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" data-filter="logo design outdoor onine photo video" class="filter">All</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" data-filter="logo" class="filter">Logos</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" data-filter="design" class="filter">Design</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" data-filter="outdoor" class="filter">Outdoor</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" data-filter="online" class="filter">Online</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" data-filter="photo" class="filter">Photo</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" data-filter="video" class="filter">Video</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- start of sorting container -->
<div class="row buffer" id="portfoliolist">

        <!--portfolio item container -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 buffer portfolio logo" data-cat="logo">
            <div class="work-thumbnail">
                <img class="img-responsive img-center" src="_images/work/thumbnails/logo_BorealBrushworks.jpg" alt="Boreal Brushworks" />
                <div class="work-summary">
                    <h4>Boreal Brushworks Logo</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<!-- Rest of HTML after this... -->
```

live page with issues: http://dai2.designangler.com/work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you add this to the css?

```
#Grid .mix{
      opacity: 0;
      display: none;
}
```

Comment: but are you using the mix-class? I checked your code, and i see .mix_all. By using .mix_all{opacity: 0;display: none;} i got it to work. don´t use a default css propery when you have modified the target html and class/id names. That won´t work!

Comment: Yea, that did it. I followed a tutorial on this and must have missed something. Thank you for your help.